# What are the benefits to compiling node.js over using the binary?

Tags: node.js, compilation, binary

I've been searching for the answer to this question. I've recently learned of instances where node can't compile on systems because of compilers being out of date. I've noticed that a binary from node's website works just fine on the system and on docker containers. So what's the benefit of me compiling from source?

Comment: If you're running on a supported platform, there is no advantage to compiling yourself unless you are changing the node.js source and need to compile in your own changes.

Comment: That's interesting to know, I'm definitely not changing the node.js source.

Comment: The only other reason I can think of is that you may not trust someone else to compile it for you.

Comment: that would make sense from a business point of view.